# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, heap-memory

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.<init>(UTF8Reader.java:122)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.createReader(XMLEntityManager.java:2344)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:684)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:189)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:812)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:203)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:175)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:140)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:123)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.XmlRootElementJaxbProvider.readFrom(XmlRootElementJaxbProvider.java:140)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.AbstractRootElementJaxbProvider.readFrom(AbstractRootElementJaxbProvider.java:122)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:239)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:211)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1109)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:853)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:785)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse$1.call(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:111)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:397)
        at   org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.readEntity(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:108)
```

My heap space is -Xmx256m. Is that the cause of this issue? If it is increased to -Xmx2g it might fail after some more time. But I don't think it is the correct solution. Please help.

Comment: Have you profiled the application to see where the memory is being used? If not, that would be a good first step.

Comment: How big is your XML file? From what I see, it tries to allocate a buffer to read your XML file and it runs out of memory.

Comment: You're presumably reading an XML file when this happens. If the XML file keeps growing then yes, it may fail with -Xmx2g after you've octupled your XML file size. But if the XML file size is constant or known then you can find out how much memory you need at most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. The heap is being over-allocated. The only way to solve other then increasing the heap space is to see what is using all the heap space and then trying to make sure objects can be collected that stay around longer then they are needed. If it is a file or something that can't be collected that is making you run out of heap space, you should re-engineer your program if the file sizes aren't constant and keep changing. If they are constant just increase the heap space above the file size.